# How to disable special dates using angular ui datepicker

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular ui datepicker. I am disabling weekends. Along with that how can disable special dates.

My Special dates are (MM/dd/yyyy):

- 03/30/2017
- 04/28/2017
- etc.

Below is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group datePicker">
              <input id="dt-date" name="dt-date" class="form-control"
                type="text" size="10" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default'}"
                required required-err-message="Date is Required"
                uib-datepicker-popup="{{TestVm.datePickerFormat}}"
                ng-model="TestVm.date"
                is-open="TestVm.dateDatePicker.isOpen"
                datepicker-options="TestVm.datePickerOptions"
                close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="TestVm.datePickerAltInputFormats" />

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button type="button" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default'}" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="TestVm.dateDatePicker()">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Datepicker options in Angular Controller

```
TestVm.datePickerOptions = {
                formatYear: 'yy',
                startingDay: 1,
                showWeeks: false,
                dateDisabled: myDisabledDates
            };
```

Function which disables weekends

```
function myDisabledDates(dateAndMode) {

        return (dateAndMode.mode === 'day' && (dateAndMode.date.getDay() === 0 || dateAndMode.date.getDay() === 6)) ;
    }
```

i already tried this but doesn't work also

```
function myDisabledDates(dateAndMode) {
var holidays = [ new Date(2017, 3, 30), new Date(2017, 3, 31), ];
return (dateAndMode.mode === 'day' && (dateAndMode.date.getDay() === 0 || dateAndMode.date.getDay() === 6 || holidays.indexOf(dateAndMode.date) != -1)); }
```

Comment: what does `dateAndMode.mode === 'day'` imply ?

Comment: Its not required actually. Here is updated question

Comment: @ModarNa any idea?

Comment: i would add a debugger in `myDisabledDates` in an if statement where `dateAndMode.date === new Date(2017,3,30)`

Comment: another is like `dateAndMode.date.getMonth()===3 && dateAndMode.date.getDay() ===31` just in case the datepicker depends on reoccurring the year instance

Comment: any idea to pick up dates from array

Comment: or maybe use `==` just in case

Comment: does not work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139403/discussion-between-modar-na-and-user1030181).